# Purpose of the Unnormalized Directional Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There are 2 definitions of the directional derivative:

Here is the more popular version:
$$\nabla _{\vec v}f = \nabla f \cdot \vec{v}  $$

The Normalized version:
$$\nabla _{\vec v}f = \frac{\nabla f \cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}  $$

Also, if you restric the vector to already being normal, these are equivalent.
What I am wondering is the purpose of this first definition, if the derivative is the rate of change, and the directional derivatvie is the rate of change in a certain direction, then shouldn't only the second definition valid?

The second tells us how $f$ changes with respect to a tiny nudge in the direction of $\vec{v}$, and this is irrespective of the length of $\vec{v}$ (all evaluated at the input variables).

I am finding it difficult to understand why we would want to use the first one, it only tells us the rate of change of $f$ with respect to a tiny nudge in the direction of $\vec{v}$, but also respective to the length of $\vec{v}$. If we march a tiny amount: $\vec{\Delta v}$ (I apologize if this is an abuse of notation) in $\vec{v}$ 's direction, then the change in $f$ would be approximated by the directional derivative (first definition) multiplied by the ratio of the lengths of; $\vec{\Delta v}$ to $\vec{v}$.

Here is what I am trying to say:

$$ \Delta f \approx (\nabla f \cdot \vec{v}) \frac{||\vec{\Delta v}||}{||\vec{v}||} $$

Using the second the definition, all we have to do is multiply by the length of change in the inputs:

$$ \Delta f \approx \left( \frac{\nabla f \cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}\right)||\vec{\Delta v}|| $$

So wouldn't it be much easier to use the second definition?

Thank you for reading this question, even if you didn't answer. I am sorry if I have missed something or if there is a mistake in my thought process, thinking about rates of change of multiple variables is new to me.

Comment: The first version has the advantage that the function $v \mapsto D_v f(x)$ is a linear function.

Comment: Suppose you start at $x$ and move with velocity $v$. Your position at time $t$ is $x + tv$. The instantaneous rate of change of $f$ at time $0$ is $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} = D_v f(x)$.